# PHP - How to return all the values of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a following function to get related keywords from Google.

```
function getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle($keyword) {
    $keywords = array();
    $data = file_get_contents('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q='.urlencode($keyword));
    if (($data = json_decode($data, true)) !== null) {
        $keywords = $data[1];
    }

    return $keywords;
}
function array_values_recursive($ary)  {
    $lst = array();
    foreach( array_keys($ary) as $k ) {
        $v = $ary[$k];
        if (is_scalar($v)) {
            $lst[] = $v;
        } elseif (is_array($v)) {
            $lst = array_merge($lst,array_values_recursive($v));
        }
    }
    return $lst;
}
print_r(getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle('Faviana Sweetheart'));
```

However, the output from this function give Array as

```
Array ( [0] => faviana sweetheart chiffon gown [1] => faviana sweetheart dress [2] => faviana sweetheart chiffon gown blue [3] => faviana sweetheart chiffon gown red [4] => faviana sweetheart chiffon gown black [5] => faviana sweetheart [6] => faviana sweetheart chiffon [7] => faviana sweetheart gown [8] => faviana strapless sweetheart dress [9] => faviana strapless sweetheart chiffon dress )
```

I want to know how it possible to output as string variables as

```
faviana sweetheart chiffon gown, faviana sweetheart dress, faviana sweetheart chiffon gown blue, ..., faviana strapless sweetheart chiffon dress
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`implode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert array into string as

```
$arr=getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle('Faviana Sweetheart');

echo $str = implode (", ", $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

In php we can use `implode()` function to convert an `array` into `string`.You can do like this:

```
$yourArray = getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle('Faviana Sweetheart');
$string = implode (", ", $yourArray); 
print_r ($string );
```